# How can I run a conditional if/else statement on slider's value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the chosen number of the range slider and print in console if it's > 200 China else Poland I have the next code:

```js
var poblacionNum = document.getElementById('poblacionNum').value;

function pais() {
  var poblacionNum = document.getElementById('poblacionNum').value;
  if (poblacionNum > 0) {
    console.log("China");
  } else {
    console.log("Poland");
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="parametros-text">
  <p>Población: <span id="poblacionNum">125</span></p>
  <input type="range" id="poblacion-slider" name="poblacion" min="10" max="500" step="1" value="125">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this simple code:

```js
function pais(poblacionNum){
  document.getElementById('poblacionNum').innerHTML = poblacionNum;
  if(parseInt(poblacionNum) > 200){
    console.log("China");
  }else{
    console.log("Poland");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parametros-text">
  <p>Población: <span id="poblacionNum">125</span></p>
  <input type="range" id="poblacion-slider" name="poblacion" min="10" max="500" step="1" value="125" oninput="pais(this.value)" onchange="pais(this.value)">
</div>
```

Comment: you have to use `this.valueAsNumber` or parse it as a number

Comment: I has edited my answer with `if(parseInt(poblacionNum) > 200){`